# How do you calculate the energy to mass relationship?

Tags: special-relativity, mass-energy

## Context

I recently asked about whether [Replicators](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/749212/316569) would theoretically be a perpetual motion machine. I think the answer is "No", as

$E=mc^{2}$

so

$\frac{E}{c^{2}}=m$

A battery of size N would, I think, need to make a battery of size <N, thereby limiting the capacity of the second battery. Additionally, it would be a physical device in the real world, so would always lose some energy to heat.

## Question

If you have a battery with a capacity of 10 terawatt-hours, $E$,

$m=\frac{E}{c^{2}}$

$m=\frac{10}{299792458^{2}}$

$m=\frac{10}{89875517873681764}$

$m=1.1126500560536184321740899648480099916075324344749623744662×{10^{-16}}$

Have I misunderstood? If not, what units is $m$ expressed in?

Comment: *what units is $m$ expressed in?* The units of $E$ divided by the units of $c^2$.

Answer (score 4):

The mass you calculated represents how much lighter, i.e. less massive, your battery will be when it is discharged compared to when it is charged.  All of the atoms will still be there but in their discharged configuration they collectively will have less mass.

I’m not exactly sure what the units would be.  One way to do the calculation is to converting the 10 terawatt hours to 36 000 terawatt seconds which is 36 000  terajoules.  Now, if you use the speed of light in m/s, the mass will be in kilograms.

When I ran the numbers I got a mass difference of 0.40 kg.

As to replicators - that is above my pay grade.

Comment: *I’m not exactly sure what the units would be.* In the OP’s calculation, they are (terawatt-hours)(seconds)^2/(meters)^2, which are not units anyone uses for mass.